# SVM: one_vs_rest error

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm, svmlight

I use libsvm to do SVM Classification and I use one-over-rest method. The problem is when I run the following command, I found the values for "accuracy" are not all real numbers, there is NaN in it. Can anyone tell me how to fix the problem? Thank you so much!

```
model = ovrtrainBot(trainLabel, trainData, bestParam);

[predict_label, accuracy, decis_values] = ovrpredictBot(testLabel, testData, model);
```

There are strange values in "accuracy":

```
accuracy=[92.56 93.39   97.521  92.562  91.74 92.562    93.39   93.39 93.39
         0.074  0.07     0.025  0.074   0.083   0.074   0.07    0.066   0.066
         0.73   0.13     0.65   NaN     0.0007  NaN     0.104   0.433   0.104]
```

Comment: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f427

Comment: @rayryeng  Thank you so much! I am trying to fix the problem!

Comment: @rayryeng, in my computer, I do not have VPN, I never set up one. It seems it is not this problem.

Comment: @rayryeng, even if I disconnect the entire network, the result still has "NaN", I do not think VPN is the reason to cause NaN.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure. I'll have to look into it for you

Comment: @rayryeng, my dataset was z-scored before I put it into SVM. Do you think z-scoring the dataset is the reason to cause the value "NaN"?

Comment: @rayryeng, I send you an email. Please take a look at it. Thank you! Waiting for your response.